# Is it possible to use a windows 7 professorial/ultimate as a cheap server?

Tags: windows-7

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can you help me with my software licensing question?](https://serverfault.com/questions/215405/can-you-help-me-with-my-software-licensing-question)

Is it possible to use a windows 7 professorial/ultimate as a cheap server?
Install IIS and have 40-50 users connected to a tcp service.

We have a customer that dont want to buy a windows server licens and want to use a "normal" windows 7 computer as a server.
Will there be any problems with that?
Our service that they will use is a TCP service that they connect to though a desktop klient. They will also be using IIS for downloading files.
Our service will use SQLExpress as DB

From a quick google i saw something about a limit on concurrent connection. Is that a problem or does that only apply to remote access, which they dont need.

Comment: Side note:  I would drop a customer like a hot rock if they didn't want to purchase a copy of Server for, um, serving...

Comment: because it almost always leads to "here's a copy of Server" on a DVD marked with a sharpie, and a "license key" written down on a piece of paper, followed by, "just install this"...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not possible that way, you can only have up to 10 connections at the same time on Windows 7.

EDIT:
The limit is 20 connecions in Windows 7.

Answer (score 0):

Windows Web Server 2008 is pretty cheap; if they won't go for that, see if they would be eligible for the [BizSpark program](http://www.microsoft.com/bizspark/).

Answer (score 0):

From a command prompt with administrative privileges, type "net config server" and it'll show you the connection limit (which, as Ninja said, is 20 on Win7).